# Am I using the ORDER BY clause incorrectly

Tags: mysql, order-by, sql-injection

I am trying to enumerate a database, created specifically for the purpose of learning SQL injections. I am trying to discover the number of columns a particular select statement might be using. I do this by "Ordinal" ordering the result set. So, I start with ORDER BY 1, .. BY 2, and so on until I get an error returning 'Unknown column'. Now, for an injection like so:

`localhost/sqli?id=2' order by 7 AND  '1`

The resulting SQL statement is:

`mysql> SELECT * FROM table_name where id='2' order by 7 and '1';`

This returns a result set, but I was expecting it to throw an error returning `"unknown column '7' in 'order clause' ".` Why does it not throw the error. The table that I am working with has only 3 columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample in [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2581/24103)-

The [syntax for the select statment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html) is the following

```
SELECT
    ...
    [ORDER BY {col_name | expr | position}
      [ASC | DESC], ...]
    ...
```

in the statement

```
SELECT * FROM table_name where id='2' order by 7 and '1';
```

`7 and '1'` must be interpreted as expression by the parser: `7` is the 
integer 7 and not a row position in the select list. The [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/logical-operators.html#operator_and) says

> Logical AND. Evaluates to 1 if all operands are nonzero and not NULL,

so the expresion evaluates to `1`